# Docker. Does restart container means the same as restart process from CMD instruction?

Tags: docker

I have a container with ubuntu and CMD instruction in Dockerfile is:

```
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/opt/jetty/start.jar"]
```

which is actually working fine.

But when I need to change configuration of my application and restart JETTY - I do restart container.

```
docker restart my_container_name
```

But this restart does not take into account and changes are not applied to the application.

I check the same not in docker - and restart JETTY - everything works.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly constitutes "change configuration of my application"? If doing that is editing configuration files and those are built into your container (as opposed to be accessed via mounted volumes), you'll need to go back to `docker build` and all subsequent steps before those changes will take effect in the running container.

Comment: App which deployed on jetty interacts with another server deployed on another PC. And when I change server configuration, I need to restart jetty. 

Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Right but how does your dockerized jetty actually get that configuration at runtime? Environment variables or the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

you need to rebuild when your configuration (Dockerfile) is changed:

```
sudo docker build .
```

Comment: App which deployed on jetty interacts with another server deployed on another PC. And when I change server configuration, I need to restart jetty. 

Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: why do you need to restart jetty if the changes are on another pc or container? what kind of changes are you referring to??

Comment: Sorry. I found an appropriate error message. Problem not in the JETTY but in access to the container. So this question is obsolete.

But the problem for me is:

if in one script I do restart container and request to the jetty service - I get error message: [Errno 61] Connection refused from Python. 
If I run them separately, then everything works fine. 

Cannot find a cause for this behaviour.
Thanks
regards